# How to write a SQL statement to show more than min values of one table and display information from another table?

Tags: mysql

How to write a SQL statement to show names and salaries of all the instructors in the ‘Mathematics’ department who make more than the min salary in the ‘Mathematics’ department?

Table 1: Instructor

```
mysql> DESCRIBE Instructor;
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| instructor_id | int         | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name          | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| salary        | int         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| dept_name     | varchar(50) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| course_id     | int         | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Table 2: Department

```
mysql> DESCRIBE Department;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| dept_name   | varchar(50) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| budget      | int         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| building_id | int         | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: `ORDER BY salary LIMIT 1, 18446744073709551615` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

A sub-select is one way:

```
SELECT x.name, x.salary 
FROM Instructor x
WHERE salary > (SELECT MIN(salary) 
                FROM Instructor y
                WHERE x.dept_name = y.dept_name)
  AND x.dept_name = 'Mathematics'
```

Or you can slightly adjust your query to:

```
SELECT Instructor.name
     , Instructor.salary
     , T.min_salary
FROM Instructor
JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(salary)
    FROM Instructor
    WHERE Instructor.dept_name = 'Mathematics'
) AS T (min_salary)
    ON Instructor.salary > T.min_salary;
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you for your help :)